# Is it bad to use two slots that are not adjacent to each other?

Tags: memory

I've heard that you always want the same size of RAM (2x1GB sticks) but does their placement matter? I have four slots on my motherboard but does it matter if the sticks are not adjacent?

This particular question involves the [Gateway GM5474](http://support.gateway.com/s/PC/R/1009568/1009568sp2.shtml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For dual channel configuration and best performance DIMMs (dual inline memory module) need to be installed in pairs.

look at the pic of dual channel memory slot shown below.

[image]

The colors indicate which channel the RAM belong to,channel 0 or channel 1, e.g. lets assume orange is channel 0 and yellow is channel 1(in this picture).Keep in mind that sometimes socket color may also indicates bank as shown in the below picture,G:violet > bank 0 ,orange >bank 1

[image]

4 slots in the DIMM suggests that these are divided into 2 banks, and each bank consists of two memory slots.(1 orange slot + 1 yellow slot which are adjacent makes bank 0,PICTURE 1)
(violet is bank 0 in PICTURE 2)

Then one can place a matched pair of memory modules in bank 0, but a different-capacity pair of modules in bank 1, as long as they are of the same speed.

Using this scheme, a pair of 2 GB memory modules in bank 0 and a pair of matched 4 GB modules in bank 1 would be acceptable for dual-channel operation.

Modules rated at different speeds can be run in dual-channel mode, although the motherboard will then run all memory modules at the speed of the slowest module.

It is adviced not to put different size and speed of ram into a bank.

Comment: I had two sticks of ram side-by-side in the same color, (same speed and size) I had run memtest86+ to determine if the RAM was bad and the second slot of RAM produced errors (as determined by yank and retest) I then plugged it into the third slot and reran tests again without error, what do you suggest?

Comment: Since there is no error with RAM in the third slot we may assume this to be a problem with second slot.

Comment: So the first set of slots may not provide the speed that the second slots would?

Comment: @Ashlie - Your explanation is confusing banks with channels.  The socket color sometimes indicates channel, but sometimes indicates bank.  *"place a matched pair of memory modules in bank 0"* is correct for the better performing dual-channel operation.  Dual channel means that two (2) channels are used simultaneously in the same bank.

Comment: @sawdust i have made some corrections and i hope they are ok if my understanding about slots,banks are correct.please verify it.

Answer (score 2):

It completely depends on how the board itself is wired. Some may require pairs to be in the same place in two separate "banks", some may require them in the same "bank". Others may work with them in either placement, but run faster with one than the other. Consult the motherboard manual for detailed information.

Comment: It's a stock PC from Gateway I don't have the manual. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Since nothing describes the exact placement of modules, you'll have to do it by trial-and-error. But don't worry, the errors won't leave your machine permanently unusable (unless you mess up module installation badly; be careful regardless).

Answer (score 0):

If your motherboard support dual/tri/quad channel memory then it completely matters.  If the pairs don't match the size you can not use dual channel.  Dual channel doubles the memory speed and quad channel is 4 times faster.

If you don't care about speed put whatever quantities wherever you want them.  However the timings of the memory modules could also matter, some motherboards can handle more variations than others.